# Python - TypeError: generateID() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, pandas, oop

My script contains 4 classes and 1 interface. I have a method `generateID` which generate an ID according to `outputmode`, a mode (`modeCB`) and a dataframe (`data_h_f`). When I execute my class I have this error :

> TypeError: generateID() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

I'm beginner in python especially objected oriented programming, I don't know if the design of my script is good. I have 3 arguments for my method `generateID()` and 3 parameters everywere.

```
class OutputMode(object):
    def __init__(self,name,startTime,intervalSeconds,timezone):
    ...

class IDCalculation_I:
    def generateID(outputMode,modeCB,data_h_df):
        pass

class IDCase1(IDCalculation_I):
    def generateID(outputMode,modeCB,data_h_df):
    ...

class Fingerprinter(object):
    def __init__(self,outputMode,modeCB=CONST_MODE_CONT):
        self._modeCB     = modeCB
        self._outputMode = outputMode

    def generateID(outputMode,modeCB,data_h_df):
        pass

    def run(self):
        return self.generateID(outputMode,modeCB,data_h_df)

def main():
    outputMode = OutputMode('EEA','06:00',8*3600,pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris'))
    f1 = Fingerprinter(outputMode, CONST_MODE_CONT)
    t = f1.generateID(outputMode,CONST_MODE_CONT,data_h_df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class IDCalculation_I:
    def generateID(self,outputMode,modeCB,data_h_df):
        pass

class IDCase1(IDCalculation_I):
    def generateID(self, outputMode,modeCB,data_h_df):
    ...

class Fingerprinter(object):
    def __init__(self,outputMode,modeCB=CONST_MODE_CONT):
        self._modeCB     = modeCB
        self._outputMode = outputMode

    def generateID(self,outputMode,modeCB,data_h_df):
        pass

    def run(self):
        return self.generateID(outputMode,modeCB,data_h_df)
```

You forgot to add `self`. Or use `@staticmethod` decorator if you don't want to add `self`.

```
class IDCalculation_I:
    @staticmethod
    def generateID(outputMode,modeCB,data_h_df):
        pass

class IDCase1(IDCalculation_I):
    @staticmethod
    def generateID(outputMode,modeCB,data_h_df):
    ...

class Fingerprinter(object):
    def __init__(self,outputMode,modeCB=CONST_MODE_CONT):
        self._modeCB     = modeCB
        self._outputMode = outputMode

    @staticmethod
    def generateID(outputMode,modeCB,data_h_df):
        pass

    def run(self):
        return self.generateID(outputMode,modeCB,data_h_df)
```

Comment: Thank you, I added self and I don't have errors. I just have a last question, my script does not return anything. I must execute my class IDCase1 for execute my method generateID() ?